# how to load random number from a txt file

Tags: c

hey guys i really want to know how to use this function to load random number from a .txt file which contains :
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    FILE* file = NULL;
    int score[3] = {0}; 
    file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &score[0], &score[1], &score[2]);
        printf("Les meilleurs scores sont : %d, %d et %d", score[0], score[1], score[2]);

        fclose(file);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but the problem is i have to make the computer choose a sequence of number randomly 
 maybe with srand(time(NULL));
i really appreciate your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a random number from a text file containing numbers 0-9 (inclusive) is slower than using srand and rand.  Seed srand with the current time and call rand with %10 to get a (mostly) random number.

```
#include <stdlib.h> // Contains srand
#include <time.h>   // Contains time

srand(time(NULL));
rand()%10;
```

However, if you're trying load random lines from a text file, I'd suggest reading all the lines into an ARRAY of size LINES and then calling ARRAY[rand()%LINES] to access a random index of that array, which would be the same as accessing a random line of the text file.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you HAVE to get the number from the file, you can always do srand, rand etc and take the result modulo 10.